# how to redirect to folder in Apache?

Tags: apache, .htaccess

The server structure is like:

```
/public_html
    /my-folder
```

I'd like to access to the folder as:

```
domain.com/?any-query_string/my-folder
```

or

```
domain.com/fake-path/my-folder
```

Is there a way to do this in .htaccess or php file?

Comment: Dou you mean with `?any-query-string` URL params like `?id=12&name=leon` That would not be possible afaik. See [UR on WikiL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL)

Comment: Is that either OR, or do you want to be able to access that folder from both URLs? I'm curious... why? Are you accessing files within that folder, or literally just that folder - as in your example? And your example URLs do not end in a trailing slash? What other directives do you have in your `.htaccess` file?

Comment: Are you wanting to access this specific folder? Or any folder using this method?

Comment: Also apart from what MrWhite said above, please do add your tried htaccess rules file in your question thank you.

Comment: @Uwe This is certainly "possible", although _why_ is another matter.

Comment: @MrWhite you are right. I assumed that `/my-folder` is meant as a URL path. A valid URL is possible that way.